# Render Single Input from Devise registration edit in different Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, rendering

I'm trying to render a single input from my `Devise Edit User Registration Form` in a modal on another Controller.

basically i'm trying to find the right code to implement it the modal body:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, multipart: true }) do |f| %>
   <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :city %>
        <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Of course this throws a `Undefined local variable or method resource`. How can i render this correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your ApplicationHelper add following

```
    def resource_name
        :user
    end

    def resource
        @resource ||= User.new
    end

    def devise_mapping
        @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
    end
```